# Reply address does not match the reply address provided when requesting authorization

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, identity

I'm getting frustrated by an error which occurs on a .netcore3.1 app I'm working on.
Here's my setup:

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftWebApp(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctx =>
        {
            ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:RedirectUri"];
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    })
    .AddMicrosoftWebAppCallsWebApi(Configuration, new[] { "user.read" })
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
```

In my appsettings

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "ClientId",
    "TenantId": "TenantId",
    "RedirectUri": "https://mywebsite.com/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "ClientSecret"
  },
```

the azure app registration is configured correctly with https://mywebsite.com/signin-oidc as the redirect url.
I've also added the following to allow headers to be forwarded from the proxy:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});

// then in the Configure method

app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Yet I'm still getting this error which is baffling me. I thought by adding

```
ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:RedirectUri"];
```

I would overcome this but it seems to have no impact on this error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred","Properties":{"CorrelationId":"c3393560-6ebe-41ce-99fc-693c1a387474","Path":"/signin-oidc","Method":"POST","exceptionMessage":"An error was encountered while handling the remote login.","exception":"System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.\n ---> MSAL.NetCore.4.16.1.0.MsalServiceException: \n\tErrorCode: invalid_client\nMicrosoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details.You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS500112: The reply address 'http://mywebsite.com/signin-oidc' does not match the reply address 'https://mywebsite.com/signin-oidc' provided when requesting Authorization
```

Comment: `check the error message from the server for details`... Can you perhaps check the server log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that your proxy is also terminating HTTPS, so the traffic your application is getting is HTTP?

Comment: yes but shouldn't the app.UseForwardedHeaders(); part fix that?

Comment: From the error message, I could see that the application is passing the redirect url as `https://mywebsite.com/signin-oidc` but your application is configured with redirect uri as `http://mywebsite.com/signin-oidc`. The different is HTTPS and HTTP.

Comment: This was the issue. Eveen though I had `app.UseForwardedHeaders();` the proxy wasn't configured to forward anything and I was under the impression that it was which confused me. We updated the proxy to forward the headers and added Https redirection as well which resolved this issue entirely

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you did to fix the problem? We are experiencing the exact same thing for a simple ASP.NET app running in Kubernetes. Can this never work if our ASP.NET container runs in port 80 mode? We let our ingress set SSL on top.

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message：**Reply address does not match the reply address provided when requesting authorization**.  You must ensure that the redirect_uri configured in the Azure portal is exactly the same as the redirect_uri configured in the code.

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with http, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Comment: I've checked this and the authorize url has the https address as the redirect_uri parameter which is correct. Thats why this is so baffling why am I getting this message!